# generate dynamic id for multiple edittext with button click

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have one row with `EditText`. My scenario is when user clicks on a button another row will be added. Somehow I have achieved this but both `EditText` have same id. So how to assign  the id of `EditText` dynamically created. My `EditText` is in the layout XML file. Is it possible with XML or I have to create `EditText` programatically.
Thanks in advance.

```
    private void inflateEditRow(String name) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.req);

    if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
        editText.setText(name);
    } else {
        mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // A TextWatcher to control the visibility of the "Add new" button and
    // handle the exclusive empty view.
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                mAddButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (mExclusiveEmptyView != null
                        && mExclusiveEmptyView != rowView) {
                    mContainerView.removeView(mExclusiveEmptyView);
                }
                mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
            } else {

                if (mExclusiveEmptyView == rowView) {
                    mExclusiveEmptyView = null;
                }

                mAddButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }


    public void onAddNewClicked(View v) {
    // Inflate a new row and hide the button self.
    inflateEditRow(null);
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: you can set a tag to edittext and use get tag

Comment: could you give me some idea how to use tag in this situation..

Comment: use button.setId(count); count is static variable or Raghunandan is also right you can setTag or getTag also you can used

Comment: Consider generateViewId() also from API 17

Comment: @ArunCThomas what if i wnat to use it below 17. i would want my app to work on lower versions also. consider that also

Comment: @ArunCThomas http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html. should consider this also. look at 34% and 33% in which case i would want my app to work on lower versions also

Comment: ya  below 17  we can use  get and set  tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to dynamically generate View Id use form API 17

[generateViewId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29)

Which will generate a value suitable for use in `setId(int)`. This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for `R.id.`

Like this

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setId(editText.generateViewId());
                editText.setHeight(50);
                editText.setWidth(50);
                ll.addView(editText);

            }
```

Comment: how to get id of every edittext ? please elaborate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a list of possible `id`s in your resources folder, like `ids.xml` and inside it place the `id`s like below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <item type="id" name="edittext1" />
        <item type="id" name="edittext2" />
        <item type="id" name="edittext3" />
</resources>
```

then in your **Java** code set dynamic ids to your `EditText`s like this;

```
youreditText1.setId(R.id.edittext1);
youreditText2.setId(R.id.edittext2);
youreditText3.setId(R.id.edittext3);
```

Comment: i have 14 edittext in single row..and i have to add atleast 20 rows dynamicallly...Do you think this is possible in my scenario.

Comment: do you need id for them? how about put them all in an EditText array and access it by index?