# Dynamically assigning ids to edittext created on button click in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic

Im trying to dynamically create edittext in Kotlin on button click. The Button click invokes below function. The click will also increment the count value. Getting type exception while attempting it. :

```
int count = 0
 fun addrow() {
        val defect: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(id)

        val gridLayout: GridLayout = findViewById(gl)
        gridLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val eqp = EditText(this)
       
        eqp.hint = "Eqp"
        eqp.textSize = 14F
        eqp.width = 200
        eqp.id = ("R.id"+count).toInt() //Error for this command

}
```

Comment: You cannot cast that string to ```Int```. Use ```View.generateViewId()``` instead.

Comment: Please refer to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207623/generate-dynamic-id-for-multiple-edittext-with-button-click

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

You can setup a list of IDs that you'll use later in `R.id` class using an XML resource file:

1- Create the following file `res/values/ids.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <item type="id" name="view1" />
        <item type="id" name="view2" />
        <item type="id" name="view3" />
</resources>
```

2- In your activity you can call

```
eqp.id = R.id.view1
```

**Method 2:**

Since API 17, you can use `View.generateViewId()`:

```
view.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

For apps targeting API level 16 or lower, use `ViewCompat.generateViewId()` instead:

```
view.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId());
```

Comment: Thank you all for the response. Will try ur suggestions and get back to you :)